# Calling function in loop causes repeat data

Tags: php, functions, loop, html

I am trying to display post numbers (for ranking purposes) on my feed, this was accomplished by calling the function that contains my wordpress loop and returning an incremented value. However, by doing so, it appears that the loop stops finding new posts and instead repeats the content (only repeating content below this function call)such as the article title (the featured image is different because this was called before the function). How do I go about fixing this?

Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Loop found in `plugin.php`

```
function ori_load_more_func() {

//removed irrelevant code

  // Query the posts by the specified IDs, and sort by like count
    $args = array(
      'post_type'   => array( 'post'),
      'post__in'      => $most_popular_posts,
      'meta_key'    => '_liked',
      'orderby' => array( 'meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC' ),
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'paged'       => $offset,
      'posts_per_page'  => $posts_per_page,
      'post__not_in' => array($current_post_id) //skip current displayed post
    );

  ob_start();

    global $ranking;


  $posts_query = new WP_Query( $args );

  if ($posts_query->have_posts()) {

          $result['have_posts'] = true;
         // echo '<div class="load_more_single_post_container">';

          while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) : $posts_query->the_post();

            return $ranking += 1;

            echo get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );



         endwhile;

//      $ranking = $ranking + 1;
        //echo '</div>';
        $data = ob_get_clean();
        wp_send_json_success( $data );
        wp_die();

  }


}
```

Where the function is called in `content.php`

```
<div class="rank-number">
  <?php echo ori_load_more_func($ranking); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all, you could delete the `return $ranking += 1;` and replace by `$ranking += 1;`.

We don't know what happend in the `template-parts/content`, but don't forget to add a little `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` just after your `endwhile;`.

Comment: Hi @Paco, removing the `return` breaks my site. Don't I need that since I'm calling a function value? Added the `wp_reset_postdata` afterwards with no avail either

Comment: here's the live site by the way: https://www.uncvrd.co/

Comment: I would like to know if the trouble is in the query or after. Can you try to keep in your query the stric minimum parameters ? Just try with ` $args = array( 'post_type'   => array( 'post') );` and test the result width `while ( $posts_query->have_posts() ) : $posts_query->the_post(); the_title();` logically, you retrieve all post title. If it's ok, you can add parameters in your query. You probably find the problem.

Comment: yes, the loop runs perfectly and displays all posts. The only time it stops working is when I throw that function call into my other PHP file. It's as if, once the value is "returned" it stops loading new material until the iteration finishes. I mean...since this loop is in a function, and I'm calling a `return` value, wouldn't the function stop running on that iteration after returning the value? Which is why no new data is loaded?

Comment: So try to replace `$data = ob_get_clean();` by `return ob_get_clean();` and remove the `return $ranking += 1;` and write `$ranking += 1;`.

For avoid problems, you can in your function, write `function ori_load_more_func( $ranking = 0 ) {`

Comment: changed up the code: https://snag.gy/qjF2St.jpg and added the `ranking=0` function argument. This causes site Error 500